# I think we're pointing new users at the wrong "How to Ask" page

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, help-center

Instead of showing them this page

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Can we show them our new and improved page instead?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this seems to be even better fit: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late

Comment: Do we have any metrics to show how much text a new user is willing to read before posting? The second page is clearly more useful, but how much will be read? @gnat's suggestion is better yet, but I suspect that only the most diehard would be willing to absorb it in its entirety.

Comment: There may also be value in sexing up the documentation (Example: the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)).

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: I actually think that [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is the first one all Stack Overflow users should see before they ask their first question, but I don't think I'm going to get that.

Comment: Nowadays both links points to [ask] (\[ask])